# Mailer plugin throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.1

When I try to use the Mailer Plugin (version 2.1-SNAPSHOT) as explained [here](https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/tree/master/mailer#using-it-from-java) everything seems fine, meaning all dependencies are resolved and there are no compilation errors.

However when this code is executed

```
MailerAPI mail = play.Play.application().plugin(MailerPlugin.class).email();
```

I get a NullPointerException on this line. The exception is generated because the call to `plugin` returns `null`.

Any hints on what is going on here?

I'm using Play 2.1-RC2 and the app is written in Java.

Comment: Did you add `1500:com.typesafe.plugin.CommonsMailerPlugin` to your `conf/play.plugins` ?

Comment: It was as easy as that... First line in the [docs](https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/tree/master/mailer#installation)... Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

As explained in the comments, please check that you add `1500:com.typesafe.plugin.CommonsMailerPlugin` to your `conf/play.plugins` in order to register the plugin as explained in the [documentation](https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/tree/master/mailer).

I think that Play should throw an explicit message instead of a `NullPointerException`.