# Java Playframework 2.3.* and MailerPlugin

Tags: java, email, playframework-2.3

Apparently to send mail with the Mailer Plugin in Java, you start by getting an instance of the `MailerAPI`:

```
MailerAPI mail = MailerPlugin.email();
```

In Playframework version 2.7.3 I get

```
non-static method email() cannot be referenced from a static context
```

`MailerPlugin` is a Scala Trait. I thus cannot instanciate it nor do I know which class reliably uses/implements that trait (In which case I could create an instance and call `email()` on it...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an entry missing in `conf/play.plugins` as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer):

```
1500:com.typesafe.plugin.CommonsMailerPlugin
```

See also [SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14314539/132396)

Answer (score 1):

Try instantiating it like this :

```
MailerAPI mailer = Play.application().plugin(MailerPlugin.class).email();
```

Comment: `MailerPlugin plugin = application.plugin(MailerPlugin.class);` actually returns `null`... Do I need something that implements it?